# How to initialize a char array at declaration

Tags: c, gcc

Are these 2 methods equivalent ?

```
char a[10] = "";
char a[10] = { 0 };
```

Also, I would like to declare-initialize a struct but this will not work in gcc:

```
struct c
{
    char d[10];
    int e; 
};
struct c f = { 0 };
```

a.c: In function ‘main’:
a.c:33: warning: missing braces around initializer
a.c:33: warning: (near initialization for ‘f.d’)
a.c:33: warning: missing initializer
a.c:33: warning: (near initialization for ‘f.e’)
a.c:33: warning: unused variable ‘f’

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Yes, they are equivalent.
2. Under default options, the structure initialization compiles without warning.  If you set the compiler to fussy, then you need to provide a string (either of the two forms in your first question) and an integer:

   ```
   struct c
   {
       char d[10];
       int e; 
   };
   struct c f = { "", 0 };
   struct c g = { { 0 }, 0 };
   ```

---

What does 'fussy' mean:

```
Osiris-2 JL: cat x.c
struct c
{
    char d[10];
    int e; 
};
struct c f = { 0 };
Osiris-2 JL: gcc -c x.c
Osiris-2 JL: gcc -Wall -c x.c
x.c:6: warning: missing braces around initializer
x.c:6: warning: (near initialization for ‘f.d’)
Osiris-2 JL: gcc -O -Wall -c x.c
x.c:6: warning: missing braces around initializer
x.c:6: warning: (near initialization for ‘f.d’)
Osiris-2 JL: gcc -O -Wextra -Wall -c x.c
x.c:6: warning: missing braces around initializer
x.c:6: warning: (near initialization for ‘f.d’)
x.c:6: warning: missing initializer
x.c:6: warning: (near initialization for ‘f.e’)
Osiris-2 JL:
```

In this context, GCC 'set fussy' means adding options like '-Wall' and '-Wextra' to get more warnings than are required by the C standard that GCC is compiling to.  Since I didn't specify which standard, it is working to the GNU-99 standard (`-std=gnu99`).

To get the 'unused variable' message from the question, I would have to make the variable f into a static variable.

Comment: With gcc -Wall to enable all warnings, in MSVC it's warning level 4 in one of the options

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the two char[] initialisations are identical - both will initialise the array to contain zeros.

For the structure problem, try:

```
struct c f = { {0}, 0 };
```

(With newer versions of gcc that support C99 you can also [name the elements of the structure being initialised.](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html))

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes they are equivalent.
2) Try

```
struct c f = { "", 0 }
```

You must initialize both value. I remember having issues too, you can try

```
struct c f = (struct c){ "", 0 }
```

if it doesn't work.

See [this page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/macxhelp/v6v81/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.vacpp6m.doc/language/ref/clrc03strin.htm) too.

Comment: There no requirement to "initialize both values".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the first two initialization are equivalent.

The second initialization *will* work in GCC. Your code is perfectly correct. In C language the `{ 0 }` is an *Universal Zero Initializer* usable with virtually any type. This is an old and very well established idiom. What you get from GCC is just *warnings*, put there by someone who made a rather clueless decision to interfere with the functionality of the *Universal Zero Initializer*.

[rant]GCC has been going down the drain lately in some respects.[/rant] I understand their general intent, but the specific `{ 0 }` form should have been handled as a warning-less exception.